# Loop inside loop only running once

Tags: php

For educational purposes I'm trying to build a [PUG](http://jade-lang.com/) Parser. 
I have two loops, one loops the lines of the PUG-Code, the other loops unclosed tags I saved last iteration.

**In my code it seems like the inner loop is only run once, because when I put `echo` statements for debugging I'm not getting enough output.**

```
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    #Increment the line number
    $lineNum++;

    #Save the current indentation for later use
    $currentIndentation = strspn($line, " ");

    #Go though list of unclosed tags and recursivley close all that need to be closed
    foreach ($unclosed_tags as $lineNum => $tag) {
        #Assign a variable to the tag indentation
        $tagIndentation = $tag[1];

        echo $tag[0] . "$tagIndentation:$currentIndentation=" . !($tagIndentation < $currentIndentation) . "<br>";

        #Check if the current indentation is not smaller than the tag
        if (!($tagIndentation < $currentIndentation)) {
            #Close the tag
            $output .= "</" . $tag[0] . ">";
            #Remove the tag from unclosed list cince we just closed it
            $unclosed_tags = array_diff($unclosed_tags, array($unclosed_tags[$key]));
        }
    }

    #Get the current element (== the first string in a string)
    $currentElement = preg_replace('/(\s*)([^\s]*)(.*)/', '$2', $line);

    #Output as open tag
    $output .= "<" . $currentElement . ">" . trim(str_replace_first($currentElement, "", $line));
    #Add to list of unclosed tags
    $unclosed_tags[$lineNum] = array($currentElement, $currentIndentation);
}
```

The sample .pug file I'm trying to parse looks like this:

```
html
  head
    title Test
  body
    h1 This page was defined using JADE (PUG)!
    h2 This a Header 2
    div
      p <strong>This text will appear strong</strong>
      hr
      br
    ul
      li This
      li is a 
      li test
    ol
      li <b>Ordered Test</b>
      li for the win
```

The exported html looks like this

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>

    <body>
        <h1>This page was defined using JADE (PUG)!</h1>
        <h2>This a Header 2</h2>
        <div>
            <p><strong>This text will appear strong</strong></p>
            <hr/>
            </p>
            <br/>
            </p>
            <ul>
                <li>This</li>
                <li>is a</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <ol>
                    <li><b>Ordered Test</b></li>
                    <li>for the win</li>
```

Appart from closing the unclosed tags this is my complete algorithm, but it is not working since sometimes tags are not closed because the inner loop can't check if more tags need to be closed this cycle!

**I am not looking for a existing library, but rather tips on why my code is not working and how to improve upon the code quality and execution time!**

Comment: I would assume that `$tagIndentation >= $currentIndentation` is returning false and so you are hitting the `break` condition which will stop the inner loop.

Comment: Also, without some sample input data and expected output, everyone would just be guessing as to what the issue is.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Thanks for yout input. I have updated my question accordingly. The break clause was still left from debugging and did not change the HTML output. The initial condition was `!($tagIndentation < $currentIndentation)`

Comment: You have a `$key` variable that isn't defined anywhere that is used in your `$unclosed_tags` array. Aside from that, after making this a working example, I get the same output as you do. I guess I'm not understanding what the issue is.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn you were right, $key is undefined. In my HTML code you can see that the head tag is not closed, because m code closed the title tag and did not check for more tags to close. Thats the issue. It stops after closing the first tag instead of "checking" the whole array of tags if more need to be closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found something that works. Here is the code as an example and I'll explain the changes below:

```
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    #Increment the line number
    $lineNum++;

    #Save the current indentation for later use
    $currentIndentation = strspn($line, " ");

    #Go though list of unclosed tags and recursivley close all that need to be closed
    for($i=count($unclosed_tags)-1; $i>= 0; $i--){
        $tag = $unclosed_tags[$i];
        #Assign a variable to the tag indentation
        $tagIndentation = $tag[1];

        echo $tag[0] . "$tagIndentation:$currentIndentation=" . !($tagIndentation < $currentIndentation) . "<br>";

        #Check if the current indentation is not smaller than the tag
        if ($tagIndentation >= $currentIndentation) {
            #Close the tag
            $output .= "</" . $tag[0] . ">";
            #Remove the tag from unclosed list cince we just closed it
            unset($unclosed_tags[$i]);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    #Get the current element (== the first string in a string)
    $currentElement = preg_replace('/(\s*)([^\s]*)(.*)/', '$2', $line);

    #Output as open tag
    $output .= "<" . $currentElement . ">" . trim(str_replace_first($currentElement, "", $line));
    #Add to list of unclosed tags
    $unclosed_tags[] = array($currentElement, $currentIndentation);
}
```

OK, so changes are:

1. I changed the way you are adding to the `$unclosed_tags` as just a straight append. You don't need to track what the line number is here and this allows us to use a `for` loop as the inner loop.
2. I changed the inner loop as a for loop. Reason is that you want to close your tags in reverse order. As you are opening tags, you want to close them in reverse order.
3. I changed the array_diff to a simple unset of the current key in the loop. By looping over in reverse, we can also keep in the break to stop looping once we are done with the closing tags at the current indentation level.

After that, the only thing that is left would be to loop over the remaining `$unclosed_tags` in reverse order and close them. I guess you could also keep the line number stuff and `foreach(array_reverse($unclosed_tags) as $i=>$line){ ...` with the same result as the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

**Break** breaks you out of the foreach loop, it doesn't just skip you to the next instance in the loop. So in this case you can delete the **else** statement, this will just simply do nothing if it doesn't match the **if**.

If your **Break** is intentional then there would be data you're not expecting/handling correctly in the $unclosed_tags variable.

Comment: You are right, the break did not change anything in the output. I still had it in my code from debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I worked out a solution. Most likely the problem was because of a wrongly declared array accessor.

```
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    #Increment the line number
    $lineNum++;

    #Save the current indentation for later use
    $currentIndentation = strspn($line, " ");

    print_r($unclosed_tags);

    #Go though list of unclosed tags and recursivley close all that need to be closed
    foreach ($unclosed_tags as $tagIndentation => $tag) {
        #Check if the current indentation is not smaller than the tag
        if (!($tagIndentation < $currentIndentation)) {
            #Close the tag
            $output .= str_repeat(' ', $tagIndentation) . "</" . $tag . ">\n";
            #Remove the tag from unclosed list cince we just closed it
            unset($unclosed_tags[$lineNum]);
        }
    }

    #Get the current element (== the first string in a string)
    $currentElement = preg_replace('/(\s*)([^\s]*)(.*)/', '$2', $line);
    #Output as open tag
    $output .= str_repeat(' ', $currentIndentation) . "<" . $currentElement . ">" . trim(str_replace_first($currentElement, "", $line)) . "\n";
    #Add to list of unclosed tags
    $unclosed_tags[$currentIndentation] = $currentElement;
}
#Close all remaining unclosed tags
```

Here is the working code.

Feel free to use it in your project (Pay attention to [StackOverflows License](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272956/a-new-code-license-the-mit-this-time-with-attribution-required) though)

Comment: There are a few issues with this still. If you look at my answer, I fix them.